# How do I do basic Auth in Zend Framework 2 http requests?

Tags: http, zend-framework2

Good morning all,

I'm trying to call an api which requires basic authentication. I'm trying to use Zend Framework 2 Zend\Http\Request, and I'm not sure which the best way of doing Basic Auth is or should I manually set a header?
I'm trying to force myself to use ZF2 and stop using ZF1 so please bear with me, old habits die hard.

**ZF2**

```php
$http= new Zend\Http\Request();
$http->setUri('https://api.my.tv/analytics/views/daily/');
$http->....
```

In **ZF1** I used to do the following which is really nice and convenient.

```php
$http = new \Zend_Http_Client();
$http->setUri('https://api.my.tv/analytics/views/daily/');
$http->setAuth($my_api_key, 'x', \Zend_Http_Client::AUTH_BASIC);
$request = $http->request(\Zend_Http_Client::POST);
```

Is there is a similar method available in ZF2 or should I write my own.  To be honest I don't know if I'm better off just using [guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/).

Jujhar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach is exactly the same also with `Zend\Http\Client`:

```php
$client  = new \Zend\Http\Client();

$client->setAuth($user, $password, \Zend\Http\Client::AUTH_BASIC);
$client->setUri('http://api.buto.tv/analytics/views/daily/');
$client->setMethod(\Zend\Http\Request::METHOD_POST);

$response = $client->send();
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm guessing my IDE didn't index ZF2 properly and it wasn't coming up in autocomplete.  Should have dug a bit deeper I suppose.